# Virtual Keyboard is lost after hiding it using IFMXVirtualKeyboardService

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have a `TEdit` and a `TTMSFMXWebGMaps` on my form. In my edit's `OnKeyUp()` event, I have this code to hide iPhone 4's virtual keyboard:

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) then
      (TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) as IFMXVirtualKeyboardService).HideVirtualKeyboard;
```

The problem is, I can not show the keyboard again without changing focus to another control. I tried this in my edit's `OnTap()`, but it does not bring the keyboard back:

```
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) then
    (TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService) as IFMXVirtualKeyboardService).ShowVirtualKeyboard(edSearch);
```

And since my form only contains one `TEdit`, keyboard is lost forever unless the user navigates to another form and comes back. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you make a ToggleButton that enables the virtualkeyboard and disables it.

Comment: @Remi No. Think about it from user's point of view

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Do you want to only show the keyboard after the first time?

Comment: @Remi I want to be able to show/hide keyboard at will. Currently, I can hide the keyboard, but I can not show it again

Comment: Ok but when exactly do you wan't to show and hide it? Can you give a more elaborate explanation?

Comment: @Remi I want to hide the keyboard when the user taps Return, and show it when she taps the edit box.

Comment: Have you tried to do it on the OnEnter/OnActivate/OnClick method rather then the OnTap method?

Comment: did you make any progress?

Comment: @Remi Nope. I tried `OnClick`, `OnDblClick`, `OnTap`, and `OnEnter` of the `TEdit` to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very simple method to hide the virtual keyboard.

```
uses
{$IFDEF IOS}
  FMX.Forms
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF Android}
  Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero,
  FMX.Platform.Android,
  FMX.Helpers.Android
{$ENDIF};

procedure HideVirtualKeyboard;
{$IFDEF IOS}
begin
  try
    Screen.ActiveForm.Focused := nil;
  except
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF Android}    
var
  TextView: JFMXTextEditorProxy;
begin
  try
    begin
      TextView := MainActivity.getTextEditorProxy;
      CallInUIThread(
        procedure
        begin
          TextView.setFocusable(false);
          TextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
          TextView.showSoftInput(false);
          TextView.clearFocus;
          TextView.setFocusable(true);
          TextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        end);
    end
  except
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: my delphi doesnt recognize JFMXTextEditorProxy as I did use Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero , any idea ?